# Symfony console to cron or task schedules in combination with task runner

Tags: php, symfony, cron

For my project, I have to import 12-15 files varying from CSV, xml to gz. Since all the files have their own structures and I had to create 1 command for every file. But this is too much and want to create a general import for all the files.

**Requirements:**

- The import script should be running every hour
- The import script should be imported category + products from the imports
- The import script has to check if my category matches the category of the import if yes it should add the information to the
  database if not ignore.
- The import should not be affecting the website if it is importing in the background.

**What I have at the moment in my command:**

```
$handle = fopen("https://example.csv",'r');

$output->writeln('Downloading done!');

$categortArray = [];
$categortA = [];
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ";")) !== FALSE)
{
    $categortA [ $row[21]] = $row[23] ;
    $categortArray [] = $row[21];
}

$output->writeln('Updating category list !');
$result = array_unique($categortArray);
$result2 = array_unique($categortA);

$distributor = $distributor->findByName("Name of Distributor");

foreach ($result as $productgroup) {
    $result = $categoryRepository->findByTitle($productgroup);
    if (empty($result)){
        $category = new Category();
        $category->setTitle($productgroup);
        $category->setDescription("Category Description");
        $category->setDistributor($distributor);

        $categoryService->create($category);
    }
}

foreach ($result2 as $key => $productgroup) {
    $result = $categoryRepository->findByTitle($key);

    /** @var $result Category */
    if ($result !== null) {
        $category = new Category();
        $category->setTitle($productgroup);
        $category->setParent($result[0]);
        $category->setDescription("Name of Distributor");
        $category->setDistributor($distributor);

        $categoryService->create($category);
    }
}

while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ";")) !== FALSE)
{

    foreach ($child as $c) {
        if ($c->getTitle() === $row['21']) {
            $product = new Product();
            $product->setName($row[1]);
            $product->setCategory($categoryTop);
            $product->setSku($row[14]);
            $product->setEanUpc($categoryTop->getId());
            $this->productService->save($product);
        }
    }
}
```

**Options what I can think of:**

- Pull all the automated import script in 1 command and run it every
  hour. This option is not hard but I do not think that this is the best solution since it will take a lot of resources on my server.
- Create a task scheduler in combination with task runner where we log every event of the different steps like download file, read the file, check if exist, check if category matches, check if the product exists, check if product stock is up to date etc. For this option, I want to create my own scheduler + runner but have no that much experience and do not know if this will help my project. Since every task will set in a queue this makes it easier to check if something fails

Advise for my current Symfony command is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was solving in past something similiar, now these advices depends on how much data you need to synchronise (I had around 8 sources each around 10 000 items witch synchronisation no latest then 15 minutes).

Architecture of solution is like this

- For each source you have Tranformer, which downloads source file, and parse it to one common TransformedDTO, in your case it could be either one Product which contain category or two transformed object for 2 different processors
- Next you have processor - This one gets TransformedDTO, now for sake of optimisation I have calculated checksum of data and compared it from checksum from last run on product basis. Now doing update only if needed. If you only insert products, then this step is not needed.
- Here you can do, that processor just check if product changed, if so you add update to the queue and have different processor handle that. But thats just next possible step.

Advantages of this solution:

- Adding new import consist of just writing one Transformer
- You can have some caching / optimisation logic in your processor (this is usually the bottleneck, as it needs to do quite some operations), but because its shared, there is room for that and one optimisation affects all.

For scheduling, depends on your needs - I would stick with possibility to run different schedules on different times and check what interval the sources are updated and synchronise your update times with that.

Example TransformedDTO. It's nothing more than just placeholder for your data and works as input to processors and as output transformers.

```
class Product {
    public $sku;
    public $category;
    public $name;
    // Everything else which your processor know how to process
}
```

Comment: @m-kebza what do you mean with Transformer / TreansformerDTO could you elaborate this ?

Comment: DTO - Data transfer object, it will be just one common object which will be used as filler for data. So the processors have some kinda of interface / contract and they know what they will get for data.

Comment: @m-kebza do you have an example?

Comment: Added small example, but rest is mostly something that depends on your concrete logic.

Comment: @M-kebza but this public sku etc is already included in the product entity model right so whats the difference?

Comment: Idea Is that your procesors doesn't data mappers doesn't need to know about your entity (and info from sources can be incomplete entity anyway).

Comment: @m-kebza but i have already an insert update delete in my productservice which does the data mapper function.  I still do not get it what you mean exactly could you elaborate a little bit more for me to understand what your trying.

Comment: Idea is to decouple data mapping from your different sources to your application. Means you can later add many different mapping without changing your application core functionality.

Comment: @M-kebza does this also include to make multiple mappers for each distributor since every distributor has his own rules and dataset some has xml, some csv etc. and not all are files are seperated by ; etc. So basically i need the logic outside the entity class and put it in service or an datatransformer.

Comment: Exactly, for each distributor you will have data mapper which will create which output will be transformedDTO, this you will process. So in the end your entity doesn't need to know how to process data source, because that would be logic of that data mapper / processor.